# How to create a MultiIndex columns from a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using the below dictionary, How can I create a MultiIndex Columns that looks exactly like the below dataframe.

```
dic = {'S1':["2013-11-12", "2013-11-13"],
       'S2':["2013-11-15", "2013-11-17"]}
```

dataframe

```
        S1                             S2                      
Start          Stop            Start          Stop     
2013-11-12     2013-11-13      2013-11-15     2013-11-17
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pd.DataFrame(dic, index=['Start', 'Stop']).unstack().to_frame().T
```

Output:

```
           S1                      S2            
        Start        Stop       Start        Stop
0  2013-11-12  2013-11-13  2013-11-15  2013-11-17
```